# laravel upload file - Call to a member function getClientOriginalName

Tags: laravel

I have a strange problem today because the code that I will show you is to upload and move an image in a database + uploads directory in my laravel.

The last projects worked but today with laravel 5.4 the code doesn't work anymore and when I want to upload a new image I get an exception 
with this line:

```
Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null
```

Line :  `$licencie_structure->lb_photo = $request->file('lb_photo')->getClientOriginalName();`

Here my blade line to upload the file :

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label>Select a picture : </label>
                    {!! Form::file('lb_photo' ,  ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Photo']) !!}
                </div>
```

Does someone have an idea why I get an exception :  `Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null`?

Thanks a lot in advance friends!

Comment: Why are you using $licencie_structure and not $request?

Comment: I use $licencie_structure variable with ->lb_photo to save the file in the database table "licencie_structure"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is returning null, meaning it's not in the request object.

```
$request->file('lb_photo')
```

Is this form actually sending the upload? Did you forget to add enctype='multipart/form-data' to the form? Is the name correct?

Check the output of `$request->all()`.

Comment: in my blade , i added 'files' => true ! i check now this $request->all()

Comment: Check the output HTML of the form in the chrome/firefox inspector.

Comment: it worked but i have some fields who needs to work with others variables to insert . i have also this code in my controller   if(Input::hasFile('lb_photo')) {

          echo 'Photo téléchargé';
          $file = Input::file('lb_photo');
          $file->move('uploads', $file->getClientOriginalName());

          // test display image
          echo '<img src="uploads/' . $file->getClientOriginalName() . '" />';


      }

Comment: i checked this inspector : <input name="lb_photo" type="file">

Comment: my FAULT ! i forgot to put , NULL , on the form now it's working thanks a lot friends for your help !!! 
                  
                    {!! Form::file('lb_photo' , null ,  ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Photo']) !!}